# How to open UISearchBar like iPhone settings search bar?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uisearchbar

Is there any easy way to handle `UISearchBar` position similar to **iPhone settings search bar**? Because iPhone settings search bar is opening while pull down the screen and open animation controlled by our pull action.

I want to do the same in my app. Help me if any easy way you know.

Thanks

Comment: You can add UISearchBar in UITableView with section header and set UITableView style to UITableViewStyleGrouped

Comment: @HarshalWani, This will also work, but If section header already has some contents then it sucks. Anyway thanks for your valuable solution.Thanks dude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this animation is:

It would be the *default* behavior for showing/hiding the search bar when adding the search bar inside the scroll view (table view) on top of the cell(s):

[image]

By applying the above, scrolling to down would let the search bar to be hidden (collapsed) and vise versa:

[image]

I assume that there is nothing to do more.

**Also**

if you want to let the search bar to be hidden by default, you could achieve it -as a workaround- by scrolling the table view to the top (you might want to call this in the `viewDidLoad()`):

```
let searchBarHeight = searchBar.frame.size.height
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchBarHeight), animated: false))
```

Comment: It works but we have to set content offset explicitly to tableView for initial state.

Comment: @SunilTarge so you mean the search bar shall be hidden by default?

Comment: Well, as a workaround, please try to scroll the table view to top (`tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)`) in `viewDidLoad()` and tell me if it worked :) If it did the desired result, I will edit my answer.

Comment: It works only when we set y offset as a search bar height. `e.g. tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 56), animated: true))` So you can update your answer like this. Still its not exactly the same which I want but somehow its is similar. Anyway I'll accept your answer after you edit.

Comment: @SunilTarge maybe letting `animated` to be `false` would be better in your case...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162020/discussion-between-sunil-targe-and-ahmad-f).

Answer (score 4):

This works on iOS 11

`navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true`

And use `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`

Documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller